# How to show Topaz signature below menu in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, topaz-signatures

We are using the Topaz Systems signature pad device for signatures asp.net web application.

```
<object class="sgPad" id="s2" style="z-index: -1;" width="120" height="20"  classid="clsid:69A40DA3-4D42-11D0-86B0-0000C025864A">
<param name="_Version" value="131095" />
<param name="_ExtentX" value="2646" />
<param name="_ExtentY" value="2646" />
<param name="_StockProps" value="9" />
</object>
```

IE always shows this control on the top of all the elements. I am using hover menu for navigation and the signature control always appear on the top of menu. I tried to set the z-index but it does not work. Any idea how to show menu on top of signature?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Evidently this is known behavior for ActiveX controls on page.

Never fear! I found this workaround from 2005: [Overlap an ActiveX Object with HTML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12211/A-workaround-to-overlap-an-ActiveX-with-an-HTML-el)

The author suggests using an image placeholder while not in use, and then replacing the image with the actual ActiveX control when activated.